# How can i get the console.log result to return as a value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xml-parsing

**EDIT!!**

I managed to get alexa rank in my console.log

```
function() {
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = this.url;
var domain = a.hostname, 
req = new XMLHttpRequest(), 
cors = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'; 
function init(){
req.addEventListener('load', function(){
var r, n;
r = /<POPULARITY[^>]*TEXT="(\d+)"/g
n = r.exec(this.response)
console.log("alexa rank "+( null != n ? n[1] : -1 ))
});
req.open('GET', cors+'http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=s&url='+domain);
req.send();
};
return init();
```

Console.log (using google.com as a test):

```
alexa rank 1
```

How can i get the console.log result to return as a value? 
I already tried this

```
return "alexa rank "+( null != n ? n[1] : -1 );
return ("alexa rank "+( null != n ? n[1] : -1 );
return = "alexa rank "+( null != n ? n[1] : -1 );
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like a plugin might be blocking the request

Comment: Yes, it was a track blocker!